# Finding Distinct Generator Matrices

Tags: coding-theory

C is a binary linear code

C = {00000000, 01101111, 11011000, 11111101, 10010010, 00100101, 01001010, 10110111}

I am trying to find two distinct generator matrices for C. I understand that generator matrices will involve 3 different codewords from C (due to dimension =3) and they need to form a basis, therefore they are linearly independent of each other. However i still can not manage to find two distinct generator matrices.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If $G$ is a generator matrix for $C$, then any matrix you get from $G$ by applying elementary row operations to it is another generator matrix. A standard fact from linear algebra is that elementary row operations do not alter the row space of a matrix, which is precisely what is needed here.

Comment: "i still can not manage to find two distinct generator matrices." Have you find one? Show it to us